# Uses of IC Logic Gates in Microelectronics

Tags: integrated-circuit, logic-gates

My question concerns the following ICs:

1. AND, OR, NAND, NOR, XOR, XNOR
2. Voltage Translating Gates
3. Buffers
4. Drivers
5. Translators

I understand what (1)s do, but what are simple uses for them? I have no idea what (2), (3), (4), and (5)s do. I have already researched a little but as for uses for them I'm not sure. Examples with microelectronics in mind would be helpful (imagine a student sitting at a table with an Arduino, breadboard, jumper wires, these ICs, resistors, and LEDs).

I got these from https://www.ti.com/logic-voltage-translation/overview.html

Comment: I would not be too worried about that. You'll run into them as you need them and when you do it will make perfect sense. At the stage you are at, it seems like memorizing what they do would do me as much good as memorizing a product catalog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The gates produce a logic state on their outputs according the inputs. They was used mainly in the past (1970, 1980), example in elevators where you control the floor number according button press but only after some condition is meet like closed door. Today's they are replaced with FPGA, microcontrollers.
2. Voltage Translating Gates are used to ensure voltage level compatibility between two circuits. Example: Control 5V device with 3v3, etc..
3. Buffer serves to decrease the impedance of a signal. Consider circuit gives you output with too high impedance to work/load in next circuit. Just place a buffer between them and you have "fresh"/strong signal on the input of second one.
4. Drivers are used to control high power devices like Power Mosfets/SCRs with low voltage logic like 3v3. The Mosfets needs about 15V to control the Mosfets gates what's makes an impossible with 3v3. The driver gives you a sufficient voltage and current level on it's output to control Mosfets properly.
5. The same as 2) , but this expression is sometimes used to ICs making a translation between protocols/communication interfaces, like I2C to SPI and so..

Comment: Logic gates are still produced and widely used even standalone in some simple tasks.

Comment: (2) Is there a difference between a voltage translating gate and a voltage regulator like the one on Arduino?
(3) As for the buffer, what is an instance of it being used? Probably not in a simple LED and resistor circuit right?

Comment: 2) The speed, translators can operate more then MHz, the regulators few kHz maybe. 3) You are not far away from truth with Led example, I would extend it to power Led like 1W more, smaller stepper motor, selenoid etc.. all you need to control with arduino 20mA pins.